# default fetch size of Simba JDBC 4.1 Driver

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I am fetching data from Google Bigquery using Simba JDBC 4.1 driver . I am able to fetch 25 GB of data in approx 3 hours . Is there any way we can set the fetch size property and what is the default fetch size for this driver ?

Comment: Can you share the link of the Simba JDBC 4.1 you mentioned? As far as I know the available supported version is [JDBC driver releases (1.2.2.1004)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers#current_jdbc_driver_releases_1221004)

Comment: @rsantiago I assume that the OP is referring to JDBC 4.1, the version of the JDBC specification for Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

The Simba driver has the property [AllowLargeResults](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/allowlargeresults.htm) that allows to manage large amounts of data. Based on the Simba documentation, I would say that the default fetch size is 128MB, however, it is not documented how much is that large results.